# How to add text method to date collection select in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, time, collections

I have an instance variable named @times. This saves many datetime objects, from which I would like to select one, as expected. I used the select tag like this:

`<%= form.select(:time, @times, {},{ :class => 'admin_select' })%>`

But it shows every day in the following format:
`2021-07-20 08:00:00 UTC`

I tried using the map method, but it modifies the object. I would like to only show the times of the objects like if they had applied the  `strftime("%H:%M")`  method. Like `8:00, 8:15, 8:30, 8:45, 9:00`

I know that that´s possible with the collection_select helper, but I can´t find the way to do it.

Comment: try this: `<%= form.select(:time, @times.collect { |t| [ t.strftime("%H:%M"), t ] }, {},{ :class => 'admin_select' })%>`

Comment: It´s exactly what I was looking for, thanks!